# Intermediate fields of the simple extension $\mathbb{C}(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, rational-functions

Let $\mathbb{C}(x)$ be the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{C}$. Of course $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is a field extension of $\mathbb{C}$. My question now is: are there any intermediate fields between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}(x)$? If so, what can we say about their dimension? Is it always infinite?

Comment: See egreg's answer at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132630/example-of-transcendental-extension-with-no-intermediate-field?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you. So, if I understood it correctly, that means that all intermediate fields are infinite dimensional, right?

Comment: @cip Yes: $\Bbb{C}$ is algebraically closed so has no finite or even algebraic field extensions.

Comment: Ok , thanks. What about vector subspaces of $\mathbb{C}(x)$? Are they all infinite dimensional as well?

Comment: Vector spaces always have finite dimensional subspaces. Just take any nonzero vector not in the ground field and it will be the basis.

Comment: If $K$ is an intermediate field then we always have  $[K:\Bbb{C}]=\infty$, but $[\Bbb{C}(x):K]<\infty$. Furthermore, by Lüroth's theorem $K\simeq \Bbb{C}(x)$. Do you want me to flesh this out?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen That would be great, thank you.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen By the way I have a proof of Luroth's theorem looking at the normal closure $L$ of $K(x)/F$, $d=[L:K(x)],n=[K(x):F]$, let $Div(x) = \sum_{l=1}^d P_l-Q_l$ as a function in $L$,

the $F$-minimal polynomial of $x$ is $\prod_{j=1}^n (T-\sigma_j(x))=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) T^k$, 
we see that $Div(a_k(x))\ge -\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^d \sigma_j(Q_l)$, 
 thus $a_k(x)$ has at most $nd$ poles on $L$ which means it has at most $n$ poles on $K(x)$, whence if $a_k(x)$ is non-constant then $[K(x):K(a_k(x))]\le n$ which implies that $F=K(a_k(x))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summary of the comments (excluding reuns result that they should post separately!)
Below $K$ stands for an arbitrary intermediae field strictly in-between, $\Bbb{C}\subset K\subset\Bbb{C}(x)$.

1. Because $\Bbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, it has no algberaic extensions. Hence no finite extensions. Therefore $[K:\Bbb{C}]=\infty$.
2. On the other hand, if $u=f(x)/g(x)$ is an arbitrary element of $K\setminus\Bbb{C}$, $f,g\in\Bbb{C}[x]$, then $x$ is a zero of the polynomial
   $$
   P(T):=f(T)-g(T)u\in K[T].
   $$
   Therefore $x$ is algebraic over $K$. Hence $[K(x):K]<\infty$. But, $K(x)=\Bbb{C}(x)$, so we can conclude that $[\Bbb{C}(x):K]<\infty$. Nothing more can be said, as we easily see that $[\Bbb{C}(x):\Bbb{C}(x^n)]=n$ for every positive integer $n$, so the extension degree can be arbitrarily high.
3. By [Lüroth's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108766/l%c3%bcroths-theorem) every intermediate field $K$ is actually a simple transcendental extension of $\Bbb{C}$. In other words, $K$ is $\Bbb{C}$-isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}(x)$.